# Hide action buttons when in search mode

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, dart

I'm working on my first Fluttre project and I need help fixing 1 issue.
I'm attaching 3 images to explaine what I want to do.
The first 2 images is where everything works as it should - however the issue is in the 3rd image.

Inside my SliverAppBar I have put a custom searchbar that behaves like an image and is hidden when a user scrolls up - and that is working fine.

The small issue that I want to fix is that I want to hide the actionButtons on the far right when search mode is activated as according to image 3

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZFsG.jpg) [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKwD3.jpg)[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vFUO.jpg)

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget with NavigationStates {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Render a sliver appbar.
    final sliverAppBar = SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      expandedHeight: 140.0,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        /* Page Title */
        title: Text(
          AppStrings.homeTitle,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.copyWith(
                color: CustomColors().novaWhite,
              ),
        ),
        /* Search Button */
        background: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SearchBar(
              canSearch: true,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      /* Action Buttons */
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
          color: CustomColors().novaWhite,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
          color: CustomColors().novaWhite,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );

    // Render android scaffold.
    final pageContent = SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          sliverAppBar,
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(Constants.paddingXY_32),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
              ),
              // Page content begins here...
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: pageContent,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    );
  }
}
```

The SearchBar

```
class SearchBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final bool canSearch;

  const SearchBar({Key key, this.canSearch = false}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(56.0);

  @override
  _SearchBar createState() => _SearchBar();
}

class _SearchBar extends State<SearchBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double rippleStartX, rippleStartY;
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation _animation;
  bool isInSearchMode = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller);
    _controller.addStatusListener(animationStatusListener);
  }

  animationStatusListener(AnimationStatus animationStatus) {
    if (animationStatus == AnimationStatus.completed) {
      setState(() {
        isInSearchMode = true;
      });
    }
  }

  void onSearchTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      rippleStartX = details.globalPosition.dx;
      rippleStartY = details.globalPosition.dy;
    });

    print("pointer location $rippleStartX, $rippleStartY");
    _controller.forward();
  }

  cancelSearch() {
    setState(() {
      isInSearchMode = false;
    });

    onSearchQueryChange('');
    _controller.reverse();
  }

  onSearchQueryChange(String query) {
    print('search $query');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          /*Search Icon */
          leading: widget.canSearch
              ? GestureDetector(
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: CustomColors().novaWhite,
                    ),
                    onPressed: (null),
                  ),
                  onTapUp: onSearchTapUp,
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
        /*Animation */
        AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _animation,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return CustomPaint(
              painter: Painter(
                containerHeight: widget.preferredSize.height,
                center: Offset(rippleStartX ?? 0, rippleStartY ?? 0),
                radius: _animation.value * screenWidth,
                context: context,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        isInSearchMode
            ? (Search(
                onCancelSearch: cancelSearch,
                onSearchQueryChanged: onSearchQueryChange,
              ))
            : (Container())
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got it right, but if i got it right, you want when the app bar is not scrolled removed the close button alright? You can use the scrollController to verify if the sliver app bar is scrolled, and create a variable to enable or disable the close button..

Comment: Not really

If you take a good look at the 3rd image - You can see that the close icon is overlapping the other icons from image 1.

I don't want to remove the close icon - `rather when in search-mode` - I want the others icons to be hidden.

Do you get what I mean.